# Find Overall score and rank results

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have this data set

```
ID  subject     class_score total_marks rank    subject_type
1   MATLAB      33.80       73.30       11  Core
1   SCIENCE     39.50       83.00       4   Core
1   ENGLISH     37.60       77.60       8   Elective
1   WQP         43.90       77.40       9   Core
1   BDT         42.00       71.50       12  Elective
1   ART         47.10       84.60       2   Elective
1   COMPUTING   26.00       65.50       13  Elective
2   MATLAB      0.00        0.00        14  Core
2   SCIENCE     38.60       73.60       10  Core
2   ENGLISH     43.80       83.30       3   Elective
2   WQP         45.00       89.00       1   Core
2   BDT         41.00       79.50       6   Elective
2   ART         38.00       78.00       7   Elective
2   COMP        40.80       80.80       5   Elective
```

I wish to calculate the overall score of each student by add the total_marks of all (Core subject + the top 3 score of the student's elective subjects) and rank them from first to last.Please can anyone assist ?

My current use is -

```
SELECT student_id,sum(t.total_marks)score 
FROM ( select student_id,total_marks 
       from tab_exam_tracker 
       where (subject_type='Core') 
     union all 
       select t.student_id,t.total_marks 
       from ( select student_id,total_marks 
              from tab_exam_tracker 
              where subject_type = 'Elective' 
              order by total_marks desc limit 3
            ) t 
     ) t 
GROUP BY student_id
```

Comment: Specify server version. And I cannot find `student_id` field in sample data which is present in the query...

Comment: Mysql 5.7.  The  student_id can replace the  ID field

Comment: So what's wrong with your query? the only point - wrapping 2nd part of UNION is excess. I.e. use direct `... union all ( select ... limit 3 ) ...`